# mvcMailer complains about SMTP host, when I want to use a pick-up directory

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, mvcmailer

This has been getting on my nerves quite a bit because I can't find a reason for this not to work. I have an mvcMailer code that works if I specify in web.config to use SMTP. I don't want to use SMTP though, I want to use the drop folder. This is part of the code that does the sending:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Deviation deviation, int[] Epost)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(deviation).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();

            if (Epost != null)
            {
                var myEpost = from p in db.Users
                              where Epost.Contains(p.UserID)
                              select p;

                myEpost.ToList();

                var subject = deviation.Benamning;
                var body = deviation.KortBeskrivning;
                var avId = deviation.DeviationId;

                foreach (var item in myEpost)
                {
                    var mailer = new UserMailer();
                    var msg = mailer.DeviationMessage(email: item.Epost, body: body, subject: subject, name: item.Name, avId: avId);
                    msg.Send();
                }
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");

            //return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(deviation);
    }
```

This code works if the web.config file is configured like this:

```
<smtp from="user@domain.com">
    <network enableSsl="false" host="192.168.111.11" port="25" userName="user@domain.com" password="password" />
  </smtp>
```

But neither of these alternatives work, they all give the same error (SMTP host not specified):

```
<smtp deliveryMethod="SpecifiedPickupDirectory">
    <specifiedPickupDirectory pickupDirectoryLocation="C:\inetpub\mailroot\pickup"/>
  </smtp>

<smtp from="user@domain.com" deliveryMethod="SpecifiedPickupDirectory">
    <specifiedPickupDirectory pickupDirectoryLocation="C:\inetpub\mailroot\pickup"/>
  </smtp>
```

It's worth noting I guess, that a file is created in the drop folder anyway, despite the error. I just don't know what's wrong, based on what I've been able to find on mvcmailer this is the correct configuration to use.

Comment: And I guess you use deviantART? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like below. The below one always work for me:

```
  <smtp from="some-email@gmail.com" deliveryMethod="SpecifiedPickupDirectory">
          <network host="localhost" />
          <specifiedPickupDirectory pickupDirectoryLocation="c:\temp\"/>
  </smtp>
```